# How to pass to NFQUEUE all incoming connection packets

Tags: linux, iptables

I develop an application to inspect packets arriving on a linux machine.
I would like to send in NFQUEUE all the incoming connection packets and only the incoming ones. Not only `--state NEW` but also `--state ESTABLISHED, RELATED` for connections that are initiated by a client.

One last thing, to make the tcp handshake for all ports I need this rule to works in addition:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -match multiport! --dport 64646 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1234
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution if it interests someone.

```
# Accept our ssh on a modified port
iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -p tcp --dport 64646 -j ACCEPT

# Mark all packets of incoming NEW connection with mark 1 (netfilter connmark)
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -m state --state NEW -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1

# Push into nfqueue all marked packets (netfilter nfqueue)
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -m connmark --mark 1 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0

# Redirect all incoming connections to the userland listener to make TCP handshake
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --match multiport ! --dport 64646 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1234
```

Finally all the incoming packets go into nfqueue but if I work on the machine (update, upgrade, install...) packets do not match the rules.
In addition the redirection applies after nfqueue decision, so I log the base port (not 1234).

Comment: Why not just do `iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -m state --state NEW -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0` instead of setting connmark and then pushing marked packets to nfqueue?